# How to update extisting csv file in python?

Tags: python, csv

I want to update my existing csv file with new rows but my result is not as expected. Here I am attaching the snap of my csv.

[image]

I tried

```
with open('c_0.4.csv', 'a') as csvFile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
    writer.writerow(edgelist)
csvFile.close()
```

Comment: No need to `csvFile.close()` with context manager

Comment: I tried without csvFile.close() also but getting the same result.

Comment: What is the value of `edgelist`? Make a [mcve].  It looks like you need `.writerows()` (plural) instead of `.writerow()`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen it is not always possible to make reproducible example, that is the reason I attached snapshot of my result. 
thanks for your help!

Comment: In this case it is possible..See your accepted answer, but substitute `writerow` for `writerows` and it reproduces your problem :^)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `edgelist` is a list of tuples, it looks like `writerow` has added your entire list as a single row whereas you would want each element of `edgelist` in a separate row.

The csv module provides a method called `writerows(some_iterable)`; takes in an iterable of rows to add.

To achieve your expected output, you can try the following code below:

```py
import csv

edgelist = [(25, 29), (26, 29) ...]

with open('c_0.4.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(edgelist)
```

---

You can find the official documentation for `writerows` method [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows).